# email sending speed - how to improve

Tags: postfix, performance, email-server

I am maintaining a server to send email mailings (no spam, of course).
The current speed of this machine is approx. 2000 emails per hour.

(**edit**: actually I did a test mailing today, removing the throttling and sending a mailing to 2500 recent + active subscribers. It took approx. 1 hour and 45 minutes to get this mailed out.)

My boss pointed out that he is not satisfied with that, as he saw companies like Mail Chimp and the like where you can send thousands of emails within a couple of seconds / minutes. And they do go out, of course, as you get immediate replies, opens, etc.

My question is, what exactly is needed to achieve such a sending speed?
I mean, of course you can add to the hardware and build a more and more complex system of servers that all send out your mail, etc. And of course it is also a matter of having a clean list (no unknown hosts, etc. as they all eat up the resources of the server)

But aside from that, I am sure there must be other ways to improve this. Anyone can give some overview on this?

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments, here are some more specifics on what hardware is being used as well as sending behavior:

**Type of server**

```
Operating system: CentOS Linux 5.11
Kernel and CPU: Linux 2.6.18-400.1.1.el5 on i686
Processor: Intel Core2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93GHz, 2 cores
CPU load averages: 1.07 (1 min) 1.18 (5 mins) 0.65 (15 mins)
CPU usage: 4% user, 1% kernel, 56% IO, 38% idle
Real memory: 1.49 GB used, 1.94 GB total
Virtual memory: 1.13 GB used, 3.91 GB total
Local disk space: 55.10 GB used, 219.71 GB total
```

**MTA**

```
Postfix version 2.3.3
```

**Average size of emails**

```
Of the recent mailings, the largest one I found was just below 20k.
On average I can say it's probably between 8k and 10k per message.
```

**bandwidth available**

```
30Mbit/s symmetrical
```

**Disk speed**

```
hdparm -t /dev/sda

    /dev/sda:
     Timing buffered disk reads:  336 MB in  3.01 seconds = 111.64 MB/sec

dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync

    16384+0 records in
    16384+0 records out
    1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 23.9512 seconds, 44.8 MB/s
```

**Measurements of various metrics**

```
CPU load - see above

disk time - ???

RAM usage - see above

bandwidth usage - below data from "iftop -n" over a time period of ca. 5 minutes while sending mail.

    TX:      cum:  3.43MB   peak:  1.16Mb    rates:   5.36Kb  99.5Kb   137Kb
    RX:            1.01MB           120Kb             2.06Kb  38.0Kb  32.3Kb
    TOTAL:         4.44MB          1.28Mb             7.42Kb   137Kb   169Kb
```

Some maillog data:

```
in case this is of value, here are a couple of lines from the maillog:

Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver postfix/smtp[25768]: 6C419107802A: to=<email1@example.com>, relay=mx.example.com[123.123.123.123]:25, delay=1.6, delays=0.05/0/0.14/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1YT8ud-0004fe-Rn)
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver postfix/qmgr[2806]: 6C419107802A: removed
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) lookup (score_sender), 1 matches for "email2@example.com", results: "."=>[Amavis::Lookup::RE=ARRAY(0xaa7f358),HASH(0xac5f891)]
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) lookup_re("myself@mailserver.com"), no matches
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) query_keys: myself@mailserver.com, myself@, mailserver.com, .mailserver.com, .com, .
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) lookup_hash(myself@mailserver.com), no matches
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) lookup (score_sender<myself@mailserver.com>) => undef, "myself@mailserver.com" does not match
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) SpamControl: calling spam scanner
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) spam_scan: DSPAM not available, skipping it
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) timer set to 320 s for SA (was 480 s)
Mar  4 14:00:32 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) calling SA parse, SA version 3.2.5
Mar  4 14:00:33 mailserver amavis[26392]: (26392-01-46) CALLING SA check
Mar  4 14:00:33 mailserver postfix/smtp[25767]: A5341207802D: to=<email3@example.com>, relay=mx.example.com[123.123.123.123]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.15/0/0.14/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1YT8ue-0005BY-5x)
Mar  4 14:00:33 mailserver postfix/qmgr[2806]: A5341107802D: removed
Mar  4 14:00:34 mailserver postfix/smtp[25764]: C30371078144: to=<email4@example.com>, relay=mx.example.com[123.123.123.123]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.05/0/0.13/1.6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued on mx.example.com as 1425474034-NECyl5JAc9-0Xx8wjwN)
```

Comment: It's a matter of finding where the bottleneck is at the moment, 2000 mails an hour is extremely slow. More detail would be needed - type of server, MTA, mail flow configuration (eg. smarthost configured or direct delivery via DNS?), average size of emails, bandwidth available, disk speed, and measurements of various metrics like CPU load, disk time, RAM usage, bandwidth usage.

Comment: @jotap interesting, I did not even consider 2000 to be slow. Well, on immediate basis I can say that the mailing software that our firm uses is throttled to ~2000 per hour, simply because if I set it to a higher amount, the mail messages tend to stack up in the active mail queue, and more goes into the queue than out. I am not in the office anymore, but tomorrow I will look at the different metrics, etc. that you listed. Then I will edit my question to give more specifics. Just out of curiosity, if 2000 is, as you say, extremely slow, what would be considered "normal"/"fast" in terms of speed?

Comment: have you tried running parallel smtp servers? on 2008 hardware it looks like postfix does about 275k/hour  http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/Postfix_MTA_performance_testing

Comment: @koljanep I'd hesitate to answer that because there are too many variables. eg. sending out 2000 2MB sized emails is very different to sending out 10000 20K emails, but not as much of an issue if the mail server has a 1Gb Ethernet link compared to a 1M DSL link. Better to focus on your specific situation and determine how to maximise the speed.

Comment: @jotap I added more specifics to my question now. On bandwidth, I have not yet put this information there as I am verifying something related to this. It should be a 1Gb Ethernet link.

Comment: Looks like you're a bit low on RAM and starting to use swap (virtual memory). And it looks like you're doing virus and spam scans on outgoing mail (via amavis), you may want to disable that for extra performance assuming you know you're not sending spam/malware.

Comment: It's definitely not Postfix which limits performance with that kind of hardware and such low volume of e-mail. It's amavis + the checks it performs via SpamAssassin which slows the overall process down.

Comment: @koljanep this really helps. It's safe to say it's not a bandwidth issue given the amount you have and the size of the emails. It's also not an issue with an upstream smart host as the server is delivering directly to the mail exchangers for the domain. It's either RAM, CPU, or disk (not that likely, but possible) or a Postfix / amavis configuration issue. Can we rule in / out the virus scanner as a variable by turning it off temporarily for outbound email? The risk of this should be assessed, perhaps by looking at how many viruses have been detected in outbound emails in the last month.

Comment: @jotap Hi again. Meanwhile I found out the bandwidth and added it to my question. I am going to switch off the outbound mail scanner and see how it goes over a day or two. I took a look during the day at the resource usage of the different processes running on the server and noticed that several times I see `mysqld` running at 53% RAM, and the server seems to be extremely busy and slow during that time. It could be also something wrong with the database that servers the mailing software... Let's see what comes up after deactivating amavis.

Comment: Postifx comes with a very useful and well documented tuning tool - qshape - see http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running a mailing list on a postfix server myself, I expect to see 2,000 messages get processed at least once (i.e. they might be deferred) before you can finish making a cup of coffee.

Your system appears to be running spam and virus scans on *outgoing* mail. While it's a good idea to scan incoming mail, it's probably not so good an idea to scan outgoing mail, especially if the source of that mail is already well-controlled. We can see that this is adding several seconds to the delivery of each message, and that it is also driving up your disk I/O dramatically.

I would reconfigure Postfix to stop scanning outgoing mail. If you have a need to scan outgoing mail normally, e.g. for the people in your office sending mail from their computers, then set up a dedicated mail server specifically for handling the outbound mailing list traffic.

Comment: I have a question on this: per what I know the message is scanned BEFORE it is put in the queue, right? Or maybe not? The problem here seems to be that the outbound mail stacks up in the mail queue. So while the amavis scan might be a factor, is it really the problem? I was being suggested by another that the problem lies with the other MX servers (gmail, hotmail, and so forth) that respond too slowly, and my server has to wait for them. What's the deal with this?

Comment: Postfix can deliver to multiple destinations at once, provided you haven't [reduced its concurrency limits](http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html). Thus one outgoing message may stall, but others will be delivered during that time.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is I/O speed, as seen by the high CPU WAITING time. This can be due to two factor:

1. **postfix queue management is fsync()-rich and impose a heavy load on IOPS terms.**
   *Try this:* remount the filesystem that hosts postfix's queue (typically the root filesystem) with the "-o nobarrier" mount option. WARNING: this should be considered a test only, as disabling I/O barriers can lead to data loss in the event of power outage and/or OS crash.
2. **it seems that you are running amavis + and spamassassin for outgoing email also**. While this can be a good thing (depending on the environment and its requirements), spamassassin can considerably lower your email througput.
   *Try this:* in amavisd.conf, set `$sa_local_tests_only = 1` to exclude all network-dependent tests and `$sa_mail_body_size_limit = 32*1024` to reduce the body portion to be scanned by spamassassin.

Try the suggestions above one at a time, and each time benchmark your system. Then let us know the results.

Comment: I/O is unlikely not the problem here. The wait time is high, but not high enough for it to be blocking.

Comment: An I/O wait time north of 50% means that at least 1 time over 2 a process was ready (runnable) but stalled for I/O. This is a sympthom of a serious overwelmed disk or network subsystem. Moreover, with high I/O time latency spike up and the system become unresponsive.

Comment: No. iowait does NOT report blocking.

Comment: I don't wrote that CPU is blocked during iowait, but that a thread was stalling waiting for io completition. From iostat man page: "Show the percentage of time that the CPU or CPUs were idle during which the system had an outstanding disk I/O request." A 50% iowait means that a 1 times over 2 a process can not be run due to it waiting for i/o completition.

Comment: To be clearer: its _obvious_ that another, not io-bound process can be scheduled and run even when the CPU experience high iowait time. However, for the OP a single class of processes (postfix and childs) are fighting for I/O bandwidth, and so it has a high iowait.

Comment: No, that is not what it means at all. It means that there was at least one io request outstanding for a while when the scheduler had no tasks which were runnable. Nothing is "stalled" based on the metrics provided.

Comment: Think about that. You have at least one outstanding I/O request, which was obviously issued by a thread that now is waiting for the reply (explicit async I/O is somewhat different, but it is rarely used). While the CPU is _not_ blocked, the OS scheduler can not re-schedule the waiting thread: hence the "iowait" name. You can argue that a different thread is free to submit another I/O requests, but if the disk array is busy serving the first request, that second requests risks to not be served immediately. Modern disks manage high QD scenario quite well, but 50% iowait probably is quite high.

Comment: @koljanep: to have a direct evidence of disk utilization, can you issue the command "iostat -x -k 60 2" while sending emails and report back the output? If you can include even the measured CPU times (idle, iowait, etc) it would be great.

Answer (score -4):

**Hi you don't need postfix !!!!**

You need write multithread application for sending emails from (C++,C# .NetCore or Java)

- Save newsletter emails to mysql database
- Get MX records list for each email address from your database
- Send emails to smtp server (hostnames) from this list (on port 25 - always).

Then you can run  apps and send from single or multiple ip addresses from one VPS serwer.

> Or you can try send emails from multiple ip addreses from postfix !!!
>
> You can use C# or Java mail smtp client

Comment: Sorry, but that's nonsense in general  - sending mail is better left to specialized services like Postfix. In this specific case, the root cause of the problem was an easily solvable configuration issue. If you answer old questions, read the prior answers before.